# Spring Cloud Gateway Retry is not working

Tags: spring, api, cloud, gateway

In our organization currently we are using mule based RAML APIs(version3.9.0), which has CVE security issues.
Hence we plan to change our APIs using Spring Cloud Gateway.
I am bit very new to this, hence exploring the Gateway functionalities before integrating into actual application.
I am facing issue in Retry GatewayFilter, which is not doing the retry for the configured failure cases.
Here is my config,

```
spring:
  application:
    name: tp-demo-ms

  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: demo-router
        uri: http://localhost:8080/demo/hello/{name}
        predicates:
        - Path=/demo/hello/** 
        - Host=**10.1.0.0**
        - Method=GET
        filters:
        - name: Retry
          args:
            retries: 3
            statuses: BAD_GATEWAY, GATEWAY_TIMEOUT, INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,**NOT_FOUND**
            methods: POST
            backoff:
             ** firstBackoff: 10ms
              maxBackoff: 50ms**
              factor: 2
              basedOnPreviousValue: false
```

I am getting the below exception while calling the another microservice,

> {"timestamp":"2023-05-16T10:06:02.203+05:30","version":"1","message":"executed ==> '/demo/hello/' with status [404 Not Found]"}

Any help  on this is much appreciated and Thanks.

I tried to hit the endpoint `http://localhost:8888/demo/hello/name` and it is throwing 404 NOT_FOUND exception.

But it is not doing the retry as per my  Retry backOff configuration.
After I hit the endpoint from my console I could see that no retry is happening.

Comment: What is the relationship with the mule tag?

Comment: @aled, sorry no relationship with mule tag, my team migrating from mule to spring cloud gateway, hence I added that tag

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace `uri : http://localhost:8080/demo/hello/{name}` by `uri : http://localhost:8080` cause you already match the path with `predicates : - Path : /demo/hello/**`

I advise you to read the spring cloud gateway doc, it's very usefull.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/

Moreover, you could use eureka for registration service.